# I need mongoDB DataProvider function for my app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xmlhttprequest, dataprovider, react-admin

I need to create a custom DataProvider for my application that uses mongoDB, and I have query in format https://r8p7az51jd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/viewpoint?$filter={} - for GET and POST queries.
If I run code like this, it doesn't work

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Admin, Resource, ListGuesser } from 'react-admin';
import { UserList, PostEdit, PostCreate, PostList  } from './categories';

import authProvider from './authProvider';
import jsonServerProvider from './DataProvider';

const dataProvider = jsonServerProvider('https://r8p7az51jd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test');


const App = () => (
  <Admin authProvider={authProvider} dataProvider={dataProvider}>
    <Resource name="viewpoint" list={ListGuesser} />
  </Admin>
);

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you show the code of your actual DataProvider, so we might help you with this one?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Are you getting an error? How is the request formatted with your code?